# What is a GDATA extension profile?

Tags: gdata-api, gdata, google-data-api

I want to get the XML in atom format of a GoogleDocs spreadsheet using the [generateAtom(..,..)][1] method  of the class BaseEntry which a SpreadsheetEntry inherits. But I don't understand the the second parameter in the method, ExtensionProfile. What is it and will this method call suffice if I just want to get the XML in atom format?

```
XmlWriter x = new XmlWriter();
spreadSheetEntry.generateAtom(x,new ExtensionProfile());
```

[1]: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/BaseEntry.html#generateAtom(com.google.gdata.util.common.xml.XmlWriter, com.google.gdata.data.ExtensionProfile)

Answer (score 3):

From the [JavaDoc for ExtensionProfile](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/ExtensionProfile.html):

> A profile is a set of allowed
>   extensions for each type together with
>   additional properties.

Usually if you've got a service, you can ask that for its extension profile using [Service.getExtensionProfile()](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/Service.html#getExtensionProfile()).

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798506/906658), you need to instanciate a service like this:

```
String developer_key = "mySecretDeveloperKey";
String client_id = "myApplicationsClientId";
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(client_id, developer_key);
```

Then you can write to a file using the extension profile of your service:

```
static void write_video_entry(VideoEntry video_entry) {
    try {
        String cache_file_path = Layout.get_cache_file_path(video_entry);
        File cache_file = new File(cache_file_path);
        Writer writer = new FileWriter(cache_file);
        XmlWriter xml_writer = new XmlWriter(writer);
        ExtensionProfile extension_profile = service.getExtensionProfile();
        video_entry.generateAtom(xml_writer, extension_profile);
        xml_writer.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Analogously, you can read a file using the extension profile of your service:

```
static VideoFeed read_video_feed(File cache_file_file) {
    VideoFeed video_feed = new VideoFeed();
    try {
        InputStream input_stream = new FileInputStream(cache_file_file);
        ExtensionProfile extension_profile = service.getExtensionProfile();
        try {
            video_feed.parseAtom(extension_profile, input_stream);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        input_stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return video_feed;
}
```